# Disable mouse cursors on entire page using CSS

Tags: css, mouse, chromium-embedded

I want to remove the mouse cursor on the entire page. In Chromium 13.0 the following was working well. But now after an upgrade to Chromium 40.0 it is no longer working. On the one hand the mouse cursor is visible and on the other hand the user cannot use the touchscreen as it should be.

```
html * {
cursor: none !important;
-webkit-touch-callout: none !important;
-webkit-user-drag: none !important;
-webkit-user-select: none !important;
user-select: none !important;
```

}

and also

```
* {
cursor: none !important;
-webkit-touch-callout: none !important;
-webkit-user-drag: none !important;
-webkit-user-select: none !important;
user-select: none !important;
```

}

How can I remove the mouse cursor using CSS? Or is there an Chromium switch?

Comment: I can't think of any single reason to do this.

Comment: @Paulie_D you will wonder, but there is a reason to do this. I use a touch screen with an arm chromimum and chromium is showing the mouse cursor. I want to avoid this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not tested, but `body { cursor: none !important; }` works for me in other cases, browsers.